# Is Joomla’s built-in gzip compression function enough or is this better handled in a .htaccess or conf file?

Tags: .htaccess, joomla, compression, gzip

Can anyone confirm if the built in Joomla Gzip compression function is the best option for a site that receives a very high volume of users.

Answer (score 1):

I would always off-load this to the webserver if you can - it then becomes a deployment & configuration concern rather an application concern.